# jQuery AJAX .Post Not Working With Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login form that works fine if I submit using a traditional html form post

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="loginform">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="user_name">
            Username or E-Mail
        </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" autofocus>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">
            Password
        </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox">Remember me
            </label>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit_login">
                Sign-in
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Instead of having the page redirect, I'd like to have the user log-in and stay on the same page.  I have the below jQuery to do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit_login").click(function(){
        var user_name = $("#user_name").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        $.post("login.php", {user_name: user_name, password: password});
    });
});
```

But this isn't posting and my sessions aren't starting.  I've printed the jQuery 'user_name' and 'password' variables and they are pulling in the correct values from the form.  The variables the 'login.php' file looks for are also 'user_name' and 'password'.  There are no console errors when I run the script.

What is causing the disconnect here?

Comment: You aren't preventing the default action, therefore the normal form submit happens after you start the ajax request resulting in an aborted request.

Comment: have you checked the console to see if a post is actually being sent? and what the response is? that code does nothing after receiving the response from the server, is this done on purpose? oh and what Kevin B said

Comment: @KevinB is right. Alternatively you can just change your submit button from type="submit" to type="button" and it will no longer attempt to redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a combination of the jQuery val() method and Bootstrap's btn class that defaults the buttons styled with it as submit buttons.  I switched

```
    var user_name = $("#user_name").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
```

to

```
    var user_name = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

and

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit_login">
```

to

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="submit_login">
```

and the AJAX worked as expected.

The key was to change 'submit' to 'button' and not just delete the type assignment all together.  If no type is specified, the button defaults to type 'submit'

Answer (score 2):

You should prevent the default action immediately before sending your `$.post` to avoid the default form submit, otherwise your `$.post` will (in most cases) be aborted.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit_login").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // stop form submit
        var user_name = $("#user_name").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        $.post("login.php", {user_name: user_name, password: password});
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, I added the event.preventDefault(), but the post is still not submitting.  Any other idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's not PHP related since I can submit the form without AJAX

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean there isn't a php problem happening. On the php side, inspect what data is available when the request is made with ajax.